# Conversion failed when converting date and /or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Error is appearing in date_to and date_from while adding data into the database. 
In sql server database the data type for date_to & date_from are date. suggest some solution.

```
try
{
   cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into license1 values(@l_id,@customer_id,@d_id,@device_name,@from,@to)", cn);

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_id", license_id.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", c_comboBox4.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_id", d_id_comboBox4.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@device_name", d_name_comboBox5.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", date_to.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", date_from.Text);

   cn.Open();
   a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if (a > 0)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Data Submitted");
   }

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

Comment: Always post the exact error message.

Comment: what is the date format that user enters in textbox?

Answer (score 11):

Take the conversion into your own hands:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", DateTime.Parse( date_to.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", DateTime.Parse( date_from.Text));
```

and when that still fails, use a version of `DateTime.ParseExact()` with an appropriate Format and CultureInfo.

You might want to consider adding a more robust and extensive validation layer. Dates and numbers are very sensitive to typing errors, User settings and User assumptions.

Always assume `TextBox.Text` is full of errors.

Answer (score 4):

if user enters the Date Format  as: `yyyy-MM-dd` then try this:

```
String strDateFormat= "yyyy-MM-dd";//change accordingly if format is something different
DateTime to=DateTime.ParseExact(date_to.Text,strDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    
DateTime from=DateTime.ParseExact(date_from.Text, strDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", to);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", from);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to",Convert.ToDateTime(date_to.Text));
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from",Convert.ToDateTime( date_from.Text});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your date format may caused the issue.  You must use date format supported by the SQL provider.  Most SQL uses MM-dd-yyyy format.  So if you pass 21-1-2014, SQL server don't accept it because 21st month don't exist.

Comment: The only truly culture invariant format for DATETIME in SQL Server is yyyyMMdd.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists while executing your code, perhaps it is due to two important reasons:

1. You have used the `DateTime.Now.ToShortString` or similar auto conversion method, and
2. You changed the computers default Datetime format in the setting.

Change the Datetime format of the computer or change the autoconversion to 'parse' method.